# Saving pdf with jsPDF gives error: Cannot read property 'elementHandlers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I want to automatically save certain webpages as pdf. For that I came across [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). The code on target page was not working. So I created a dummy code:

```
$.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js');

var doc = new jsPDF();

var pdfStr = "<div><div>Mahesh</div><img src=\"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\" /></div>"

//creating dom from string
var div =  document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = pdfStr;
var pdfHtml = div.childNodes;
doc.fromHTML(pdfHtml);
doc.save('pdfjsdemo.pdf');
```

I am copy pasting following code in Chromes console and hitting Enter. It is giving me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementHandlers' of undefined
    at Object.f.fromHTML (jspdf.min.js:75)
    at <anonymous>:11:5
```

I used dom string in format `<div><div></div><img></img></div>` because thats how my target page looks like.

Besides, it works, if I use

```
doc.text("<div>mahesh</div>");
```

saving desired pdf.

So whats going on here?

There seems to be many similar threads on github. Is it not possible.
Or is their better alternative to jspdf?

Answer (score 0):

`div.childNodes` returns an array - you need to get it's first element.

Replace `var pdfHtml = div.childNodes;` with `var pdfHtml = div.childNodes[0];`

Comment: Did you really tried on your side? This is still not working. I tried exactly what you said.

Comment: also I tried using `addImage` as explained [here](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/). But mine is png. And it clearly says png is not clearly supported currently in the console error...seems pretty useless...

Comment: No, I've found this one issue in your code, but at that time my reputation was too low to write it as comment. It seems that function fromHTML takes more than 1 parameter. Check this topic: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184659/cannot-make-pdf-from-html-div-by-jspdf). Object with property `elementHandlers` should be passed as fourth parameter according to this.